# How Do I Push an Existing Eclipse Project Up to Bitbucket With EGIT?

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I have a project for an interview I need to get onto Bitbucket. I normally use Github, so the slight change is throwing me off. I coded the project, tested it, and it works fine. Now I want to get it up on the repository, but can't. I installed EGIT to my Eclipse instance on my local, and while it will attach itself to the empty online repository it won't allow me to import my local code to a do a push and commit.

Can anyone advise on the simplest way I can get this taken care of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EGit on Neon: right-click on project > Team > Push branch...., you'll see the push dialog and a button to create a new remote. Click this button, configure the bitbucket repo, Finish.
Then the repo should be available in the Push Dialog. So select it as target and press Finish.

Comment: It's easier to use this rather downloading separate software like Sourcetree and SourceTree not available in Linux

Answer (score -1):

In Bitbucket you can import project from github.

But if you want to change git remote origin and send the whole project again to Bitbucket get to this file : `.git/config` and change the `[remote "origin"]` section to the Bitbucket repo `http` or `ssh` and then:

`git add all` or `git add .`

`git commit -m "last commit massage ..."`

`git push -u origin master`

I recommand to use [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) instead of Bitbucket for private repo.

Comment: Yeah, this is for an interview so I have to get the code to their BB. If I can get it to Github first then import it that will help.